# How do we promote our site (when it goes public beta)?

Tags: discussion, 7-essential

I figured I would push this question out there to get the ball rolling (Early bird gets the worm no?). I think extended discussion of promotion should be in the chatroom http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/movies, it is alot easier than refreshing this meta page and then come here when we have definite answers to this question. What do you think?

Who do we ask? What sites should we email?

I do think though that when we do this, we should do it in one big media blitz. One intense first day where we get as much as media as once on one day (whenever public beta opens) then let organic traffic take care of the rest after that for a while.